# How to assign a different design to each button with oauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

I want to allow customers to connect themselves with Facebook and G+ auth. 
My problem is that I don't know how to assign a different design for each button, because my link call each provider. How can I call them distinctly ?

Here's my view's code :

```
        <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
      <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
        <%= link_to omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) do %>
        <div class="fb-connect"> <%= image_tag('f-facebook.png', alt: "fb", class: "mini-fb") %>&nbsp;&nbsp;Inscription avec facebook</div>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

As you understand, the two buttons (fb + G+) looks like Facebook button.

Here's my omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
def self.provides_callback_for(provider)
class_eval %Q{
def #{provider}
@user = User.find_for_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

if @user.persisted?
sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "#{provider}".capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
else
session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
end
}
end

[:twitter, :facebook, :linkedin, :google_oauth2].each do |provider|
provides_callback_for provider
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
if resource.email_verified?
    super resource
    else
    finish_signup_path(resource)
end
end
end
```

Comment: Why not make your own collection containing providers, corresponding class name, and picture info? Then you can iterate over that instead of just providers? Also you can make a helper with a switch statement based on provider name?

Comment: I solved my problem with : "<%= link_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) do %>"